# Using NSOutputStream to POST to url

Tags: cocoa, post, nsoutputstream

So all I want to do is send a POST request to a url.  Now I tried using NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection, but was having problems with that and decided to move to a lower level, also because I want to send large files and thought dealing directly with streams might be better.  But the output stream delegate never seems to be called, and I can't seem to find examples using NSOutputStream's `initWithURL`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://url"];
self.outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initWithURL:url append:NO];
[outputStream retain];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream open];
```

It seems that the outputStream is null after the init, which I can't understand because my url is a valid url--I can ping it from the terminal and send data from other sources.  Am I doing something wrong, or can anyone tell me how to write a POST request to a URL using streams?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `NSOutputStream` to send a POST request to a HTTP server.

The good method is to create a `NSMutableURLRequest` and provide that request with a `HTTPBodyStream` then create a `NSURLConnection` to send the request.

The `HTTPBodyStream` is an `NSInputStream` the request will read the body from. You may initialize it with a `NSData` object or with the contents of a file.

If you want to provide a custom content (for example, you want to upload a file as part of a `multipart/form-data` request), you may need to subclass `NSInputStream`. In such case, I suggest you to have a look at [How to implement CoreFoundation toll-free bridged NSInputStream subclass](http://blog.octiplex.com/2011/06/how-to-implement-a-corefoundation-toll-free-bridged-nsinputstream-subclass/), which explains how to address an issue that occurs when using custom input streams with `NSURLConnection`. Or you may use [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) which provides multipart HTTP requests out of the box.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I looked into ASIHTTPRequest, which looks like I could use it, except the provided classes seem to be for iOS and copying the files from the Mac Example causes linker errors.  Am I missing something?  Or do you know of any simple examples of subclassing NSInputStream?  I've looked and haven't found a clear example.

Comment: Nevermind, found setup instructions for ASIHTTPRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send the HTTP GET/POST request using NSOutputStream.

1.make & open your stream.

2.when the stream is ready to write, the `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event will be send in method:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstreamdelegate/1410079-stream?language=objc

3.make a `CFHTTPMessageRef` & and write the data.

code like this:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{
    switch (eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:{
        // 
    }
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:{
        [self sendHTTPMessage];
    }
        break;
    default:{
        //
    }
        break;
}

- (void)sendHTTPMessage{
    //create a http GET message
    CFStringRef requestMethod = (CFStringRef)CFAutorelease(CFSTR("GET"));
    CFHTTPMessageRef httpRequest = (CFHTTPMessageRef)CFAutorelease(CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestMethod, (__bridge  CFURLRef)yourURL,kCFHTTPVersion1_1));
    //set HTTP header
    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(httpRequest, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"Host", (__bridge CFStringRef)@"yourhost.com");
    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(httpRequest, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"Connection", (__bridge CFStringRef)@"close");
    //set HTTP Body
    ...
    //let's send it
    CFDataRef serializedRequest = CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(httpRequest);
    NSData *requestData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)serializedRequest;
    [self.outStream write:requestData.bytes maxLength:requestData.length];
    [self.outStream close];
}
```

Remember, the key point is converting CFHTTPMessageRef to bytes to write.